# Why doesn't django like my dictionary?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm new to django, and desperately trying to figure out why I can't get a set of dictionary objects to render. Here is a snippet of the template--with some pprints for debugging:

```
 <ul>
        {% with req.requirement_id as reqid %}
        req.requirement_id: {{ req.requirement_id|pprint }}<br />
        reqid: {{ reqid|pprint }}<br />
        e_quals: {{ e_quals|pprint }}<br />
        e_quals.reqid: {{ e_quals.reqid|pprint }}<br />

        {% for qual in e_quals.reqid %}
          qual.qual_type: {{ qual.qual_type }}
          {% if qual.qual_type == "self" %}
            <li>Only self-endorsements.</li>
          {% endif %}
          {% if qual.qual_type == "other" %}
            <li>No self-endoresements.</li>
          {% endif %}
          {% if qual.qual_type == "hasa" %}
            <li>Endorser must hold an active {{ qual.qual_data }} badge.</li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endwith %}
      </ul>
```

And here is what I get as an output:

```
req.requirement_id: u'man_keephead'
reqid: u'man_keephead'
e_quals: {u'man_keephead': [<EndorsementQual: man_keephead_others>, <EndorsementQual: man_keephead_man>], u'man_trustself': [<EndorsementQual: man_trustself_self>], u'man_waiting': [<EndorsementQual: man_waiting_other>]}
e_quals.reqid: ''
```

I really seems like--given that reqid and that e_quals dictionary, e_quals.reqid should produce that list of objects. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this sort of indirect variable resolution in Django's template language. It will always interpret `e_quals.req_id` as `e_quals["req_id"]` - ie as a literal key.

You'll need to create a simple template filter:

```
@register.filter
def dict_get(my_dict, key):
    return my_dict.get(key)


{{ e_quals|dict_get:req_id }}
```

Comment: good clean solution! @alex if you're new to django, it'll probably help to know where to put this code - check out http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Thanks! Very cool, and helpful. I ended up doing a custom template tag, and working it out that way, but this is much cleaner (and I'm happy to know why it wasn't working!)